# Closing modal in child component React Native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, ref, react-props

I have two components in react native and I'm unable to close a modal from my child component.

ListTrips - Parent

ModalAddTrip - Child

**ListTrips.js**

```
import ModalAddTrip from './ModalAddTrip';
....
....
this.state = {
    isModalAddTripVisible: false
} 
....
handleDismissModalAddTrip = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalAddTripVisible: false });
};

closeModal() {
    this.refs.ModalAdd.handleDismissModalAddTrip();
}
....

<ModalAddTrip
    ref="ModalAdd"
    isVisible={this.state.isModalAddTripVisible}
    onBackDropPress={this.handleDismissModalAddTrip}
    closeModal={() => this.closeModal()}
    onRequestClose={this.handleDismissModalAddTrip}
/>
```

**ModalAddTrip.js**

```
<Modal
    isVisible={isVisible}
    onBackdropPress={onBackDropPress}
    closeModal={this.props.child}
>
<Button
    style={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'white' }}
    containerStyle={{
        padding: 8,
        marginLeft: 70,
    }}
    onPress={this.closeModal}
>
```

I'm unable to close the modal once I open it. I know its something to do with referencing/props but I've messed around with it for hours and I cannot get anywhere. I was trying something along the lines of `this.props.closeModal;` along with switching the ref to the child component but it didn't work either. inside a function in ModalAddTrip but that wouldn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution which I use to handle modal.

```
export default class MyModal extends React.Component<Props, State>{

  constructor(props: Props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    }
  }

  // Use this method to toggle the modal !
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible});
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <Modal
      isVisible={this.state.visible}
      hideModalContentWhileAnimating
      onBackdropPress={() => {
        this.toggleModal();
      }}
      useNativeDriver
      >
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "white", padding: 5}}>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

If I press behind it, the modal will close -> it can close itself.

Now to manage it from the parent component just get a ref from your modal :

```
  <MyModal 
    ref={ref => {
      this.myModal = ref;
    }}
  />
```

And you can toggle it from the parent component :

```
toggleMyModal = () => {
    if(this.myModal){
      this.myModal.toggleModal();
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you got it working :)

Comment: No problem @OscarFen ! Please consider accepting the answer as solution ;)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: You can't click on the little "check" sign under the answer score ? Strange that you can't accept a solution on your own question ! Anyway good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

//Worked Well For Me//

MODAL EXAMPLE.JS

```
...
import Child from "./components/Child.js"

const ModalExample = () => {    

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true)

  return(
    <Modal visible={ModalVisible}>
      <Child closeModal={()=>setModalVisible(false)}/>
    </Modal>
  )
}
export default ModalExample
```

CHILD.JS

```
...
const Child = (closeModal) => {
  render(
    <Button title="close" onPress={closeModal.closeModal}/>
  )
}
export default Child
```

Answer (score 0):

ModalAddTrip.js

```
  _toggleModal = () =>
      this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });
  ....

  render() { 
  ....
   <Modal
    isVisible={isVisible}
    onBackdropPress={onBackDropPress}
  >
      <Button
            style={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'white' }}
            containerStyle={{
              padding: 8,
              marginLeft: 70,
            }}
            onPress={this._toggleModal} >
</Modal>
```

Comment: didn't work, thanks for you help though.
EDIT: Could it be something do with my state in ModalAddTrip?